# Postfix Expression?

Tags: math, expression

What is the value of the postfix expression `6 3 2 4 + - *`?

Options are:

A. Something between -15 and -100

B. Something between -5 and -15

C. Something between 5 and -5

D. Something between 5 and 15

E. Something between 15 and 100

By my calculations, I keep getting 18 as the answer, which would be E, but the answer is A.

Am I missing something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math problem, not a programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. Might be better suited on [mathematics.se]

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the order of operands to the "-" operator.  In infix notation, this evaluates to `6*(3-(4+2)) = -18`.

Answer (score 2):

Let us use  stack for evaluation of the expression **6 3 2 4  +  -  ***
Then , traverse from left to right one by one if we get operend then we need to push it into the stack and if we get operator then We need to  pop(); two times and assign the first popped element into an variable **op2** and the second popped element into variable **op1** then perform the operation which we get in traverse like **op1 * op2** then push(); the result into the stack again this process continue till last element of the expression.so let's implement the stack method for the  expression.

1) now traverse from left to right in the expression untill we get an operator and on getting operand pushed it into the stack so, 
 on traverse upto '4' , stack will be like
**6 3 2 4**  +  -  *

```
                                {  4  }
                      {  2  }   {  2  }
 {     }   {  3  }    {  3  }   {  3  }
 {  6  }   {  6  }    {  6  }   {  6  }
 Stack.    Stack      Stack     Stack
```

2)  6 3 2 4  + -  *

```
Here we get an operator '+' so ,

 op2 = pop(); // op2=4
 op1 = pop(); // op1=2
 result = op1 + op2 ; // result =6
 push(result);

So new stack will be like 

{  6  }
{  3  }
{  6  }
Stack
```

3) 6 3 2 4  +  -  *

```
Here again  we get an operator '-' so ,

op2 = pop(); // op2=6
op1 = pop(); // op1=3
result = op1 - op2 ; // result =-3
push(result);

So, new stack will be like 

{ - 3 }
{  6  }
Stack
```

4) 6 3 2 4  +  -  *

```
Here again  we get an operator '*' so ,

op2 = pop(); // op2=-3
op1 = pop(); // op1=6
result = op1 - op2 ; // result =-18
push(result);

So, new stack will be like 

{ -18 }
Stack
```

5) so, the final answer will be ,-18